# PHP opening tag showing inside html

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am facing an issue with PHP opening tags. The opening tag is displayed at the starting of the file. Here is the screenshot of the source code
[image]

Here is the code I use. I registered the template through the plugin.
I followed this [tutorial for adding the templates with the plugin](https://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-page-templates-plugin/).

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Customer
 */

if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_redirect( homer_url());
    exit();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="ud-for-edd-template">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <?php wp_head() ?>
</head>
```

I am not sure why this happens. Why the opening tag is showing in the frontend?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying that it _doesn't_ show `<?php wp_head() ?>`?

Comment: I mean it shows <?php tag before HTML. Screenshot is added

Comment: nothing to do with wp_head. I have added a screenshot to not get confused with wp_head

Comment: Is it a php file?

Comment: yes, it is a php file

Comment: added a new screenshot. Little bit of mouse error.

Comment: You should answer the first question you got from @RoAchterberg.

Comment: You do realize that's not an answer to the question? Nobody claimed wp_head() was the cause. The question was simply if the `wp_head()`-part worked as expected. That's for assessing the scope/size of the issue.

Comment: Yeppp. I have to answer as No. Thanks for pointing out.. Everything else is working as expected. I don't know why <?php before html is shown. That is the real issue

Comment: The screenshot I posted is a source code, not inside the text editor.